# Appveyor builds for all branches instead of specified ones

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, appveyor

We have currently three separated appveyor projects, one for each branch in our repository.

**Our problem is follwing:**
Appveyor ignores my filter on github branches. Everytime we make a commit to master, stage or dev it builds on all three projects instead of the single one we did make a commit to.

Each branch has a unique appveyor.yml file looking like this:

**This is the appveyor.yml for dev**

```
version: 0.0.{build}
branches:
  only:
  - dev
image: Visual Studio 2017
configuration: dev
before_build:
  - nuget restore
build:
  project: Core.Api.sln
  publish_wap: true
  verbosity: minimal
build_script:
  - ps: .\build.ps1
after_build:
  - cmd: dotnet publish src\Core.Api --output %appveyor_build_folder%\dist
test: off
artifacts:
- path: dist
  name: dist.web
deploy:
...
```

When we make a commit, it builds on all projects. Any idea??

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because each project has Webhook configured on GitHub and each time someone makes a commit, each project build is triggered by webhook. Then, regardless of what branch is configured for project (that is only default branch for manual/API builds), AppVeyor reads `appveyor.yml` from the branch where commit was done.

Solution is to use either [alternative YAML file names](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/build-configuration/#yaml-file-alternative-naming) or [alternative YAML file location](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/build-configuration/#alternative-yaml-file-location).

With *alternative YAML file names* you can have something like `appveyor-dev.yml`, `appveyor-stage.yml` files and set specific AppVeyor project to use specific file. With *alternative YAML file location* is it basically the same, but in other location than repo. I personally like *alternative YAML file location* more because of less duplication and potential merging issues.

In both cases when webhook in say branch `dev` come to `stage` project, it still will read `appveyor-dev.yml` and do the right filtering.

Comment: Thanks, I chose the alternative YAML file location way aswell. Works like a charm!